# Plot for each fold of classifier

Tags: python, matplotlib

This is my code for kfolds

```
kf = KFold(class_label.shape[0], n_folds=5, shuffle=True). 
for train_index, test_index in kf:.
print("Train:", train_index, "Validation:",test_index). 
X_train, X_test = np.array(x)[train_index], np.array(x)[test_index]. 
y_train, y_test = np.array(class_label)[train_index], np.array(class_label)[test_index]
```

the plot should look like this but with 10 lines
[image: the plot should look like this but with 10 lines]

I want to plot a line for each fold so there should be ten lines in all:

```
test_score = []. 
train_score = []. 
for depth in range(20):. 
    clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth = depth + 1). 
    clf.fit(X_train,y_train). 
    train_score.append(clf.score(X_train,y_train)). 
    test_score.append(clf.score(X_test,y_test)). 

plt.figure(figsize = (8,8)). 
plt.plot(range(20),train_score). 
plt.plot(range(20), test_score). 
plt.xlabel('Tree Depth'). 
plt.ylabel('Accuracy'). 
plt.legend(['Training set','Test set']).
```

Comment: Can you show all your code? Unsure how the top and bottom sections link. You are only plotting 2 lines - the train score and the test score for the different depth values.

Comment: Thats the code... I want to continue to plot the train and test score for varying depths but for each fold of the k-folds. As I have 5 folds I should get 10 lines. @KenSyme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you do something like this? Here I am just nesting the loops together to have a list of lists, where the outer list is the folds and the inner list is the scores for each fold for each depth.

```
kf = KFold(class_label.shape[0], n_folds=5, shuffle=True)
kf_test_scores = []
kf_train_scores = []
for train_index, test_index in kf:
    print("Train:", train_index, "Validation:",test_index)
    X_train, X_test = np.array(x)[train_index], np.array(x)[test_index].
    y_train, y_test = np.array(class_label)[train_index], np.array(class_label)[test_index]

    test_score = []
    train_score = []
    for depth in range(20):
        clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth = depth + 1)
        clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
        train_score.append(clf.score(X_train,y_train))
        test_score.append(clf.score(X_test,y_test))

    kf_test_scores.append(test_score)
    kf_train_scores.append(train_score)

plt.figure(figsize = (8,8))
for fold in range(len(kf_test_scores)):
    plt.plot(range(20), kf_train_scores[fold], label="Fold {0} Train Score"). 
    plt.plot(range(20), kf_test_scores[fold], label="Fold {0} TestScore"). 

plt.xlabel('Tree Depth'). 
plt.ylabel('Accuracy'). 
plt.legend(['Training set','Test set']).
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for but I was making indentation error while nesting loops and looking for someone to do it from scratch to correct my mistake. This is perfect thanks so much @Ken Syme